# Histogram of mean per bin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram where the bin heights are the mean of the values that fall into each bin. The code for p2 below is what I thought would work.

```
library(ggplot2)
m <- mtcars[1:20, ];
p <- ggplot(m, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 5);
p <- p + aes(weight = wt); # works, but is the sum of the wt
p2 <- p + aes(weight = wt / ..count..); # does not work, but the idea I am going for
```

Sorry if I am missing something obvious here, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: So I can see both the total value of my data as well as "per unit" value.

Comment: Why not just `ggplot(m, aes(x=mpg,y = wt))+ geom_point()`

Comment: Because that plots all of the data points (20 in this case). I just want to plot/calculate the mean of the values that fall into each bin (of width 5 in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just calculate the means with something like this:

```
m <- mtcars[1:20, ];
m$br <- cut(m$mpg,hist(m$mpg,5,plot=F)$breaks);
mean.wt <- tapply(m$wt,m$br,mean);
m2 <- data.frame(mpg.bin=names(mean.wt),mean.wt);
ggplot(m2,aes(x=mpg.bin,y=mean.wt)) + geom_bar();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had hoped that there was an easy way to just do the calculation directly in ggplot, but perhaps there is not and I just need to do the calculation externally as you suggest.

Comment: I don't think there will be using `geom_histogram` as this calls `stat_bin` which won't let you pass the `weight` aesthetic

Answer (score 4):

You can now use `stat_summary_bin` for this.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt)) +
  stat_summary_bin(fun.y = "mean",
                   geom="bar",
                   binwidth=5
                   )
```

[image]